# what rect size for retina display?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, retina-display

I just wanted to know if my image has x*y dimensions.

When retina display devices show that image created with a `CGRectMake(0,0,x,y)`, would that be a pixelated image?

Should the correct size have been `CGRectMake(0,0,x/2,y/2)`?

How can I tell the rect size that an image should have?

Do I need to use the `contentScaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`?

or maybe divide by it as in: `CGRectMake(0,0,x/contentScaleFactor,y/contentScaleFactor)`?

Comment: you have to use the same dimensions (320*480 or 480*320) for the retina display as well. you can be thinking in these values in the case of retina or normal display.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dimensions are measured [in *points* instead of pixels](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15). Both retina and non-retina display devices have the same points. On a non-retina display device, one point equals one pixel, but on a retina display device, one point equals two pixels. So, you will use `CGRectMake(0,0,x,y)` for both.

To avoid a pixelated image, make sure to provide a double-resolution image with the `@2x` suffix. For example, if your regular image was named `foo.png`, then the retina version should be named `foo@2x.png`.

When coding, refer to `foo.png` at all times. When your app is running on a retina display device the double-resolution image (`foo@2x.png`) will be used automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For non-retina image (myImage.png) size should be 21x21 you should place another image with @2x suffix (myImage@2x.png) of size 42x42. In code you can write some think like

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

This call will automatically pick correct file based on iPad.

the correct size should be

```
CGRectMake(0,0,21,21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Terms "retina" and "non-retina" are related with resolution of the display screen, not with dimension of the display screen. And resolution is related with number of pixels per inch (point).

While coding in such scenarios, dimensions will remain same only image resolutions will be changed.

To understand how to use different sized resources in application bundle, you can check this link http://panditpakhurde.com/tech/?p=365